# Execution order of c++

Tags: c++, carchive

I created a program that tests `carchive`. I wanted to see how fast it took to save a million data points:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestData.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void pause() {
    cin.clear();
    cout << endl << "Press any key to continue...";
    cin.ignore();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int numOfPoint = 1000000;

    printf("Starting test...\n\n");
    vector<TestData>* dataPoints = new vector<TestData>();

    printf("Creating %i points...\n", numOfPoint);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoint; i++)
    {
        TestData* dataPoint = new TestData();
        dataPoints->push_back(*dataPoint);
    }
    printf("Finished creating points.\n\n");

    printf("Creating archive...\n");
    CFile* pFile = new CFile();
    CFileException e;
    TCHAR* fileName = _T("foo.dat");
    ASSERT(pFile != NULL);
    if (!pFile->Open(fileName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareExclusive, &e))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    bool bReading = false;
    CArchive* pArchive = NULL;
    try
    {
        pFile->SeekToBegin();
        UINT uMode = (bReading ? CArchive::load : CArchive::store);
        pArchive = new CArchive(pFile, uMode);
        ASSERT(pArchive != NULL);
    }
    catch (CException* pException)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    printf("Finished creating archive.\n\n");

    //SERIALIZING DATA
    printf("Serializing data...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints->size(); i++)
    {
        dataPoints->at(i).serialize(pArchive);
    }
    printf("Finished serializing data.\n\n");

    printf("Cleaning up...\n");
    pArchive->Close();
    delete pArchive;
    pFile->Close();
    delete pFile;
    printf("Finished cleaning up.\n\n");

    printf("Test Complete.\n");

    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it takes some time to create the data points, but then it runs through the rest of the code almost instantly. However, I then have to wait about 4 minutes for the application to actually finish running. I would assume the application would wait hang at the serializing data portion just like it did during the creation of the data points.

So my question is about how this actually work. Does `carchive` do its thing on a separate thread and allow the rest of the code to execute?

I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Don't add elements to your vector that way!! `dataPoints->push_back(*dataPoint);` You are leaking every single element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303921/deleting-dereferenced-elements-from-vector

Comment: You also have no reason to `new` the `std::vector`.

Comment: Please avoid MFC (It is useless in a console application, and harmful for beginners)

Comment: The documentation for `CArchive` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caz3zy5s.aspx ) doesn't say anything about running on a different thread.  If you don't go through the trouble of calling the functions you want on a different thread, it's not going to do that automatically.

Comment: The documentation for `CArchive::Close()` says **Flushes any data remaining in the buffer**, closes the archive, and disconnects the archive from the file.  It looks to me like Microsoft is aggressive about keeping data in that buffer.

Comment: There is probably no reason to use `new` at all in this program.  Removing those calls to `new` makes those `ASSERT` lines unnecessary, since you would be dealing with objects, not pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a vector with a million elements that are all default-initialized you just just use this version of the constructor

```
vector<TestData> dataPoints{numOfPoint};
```

You should stop `new`ing everything, let RAII handle the cleanup for you.

Also, know that `push_back` requires a `resize` of your vector if it's capacity isn't large enough, so if you start with an empty vector, and know how big it is going to be at the end, you can use `reserve` ahead of time.

```
vector<TestData> dataPoints;
dataPoints.reserve(numOfPoint);
for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoint; i++)
{
    dataPoints->push_back(TestData{});
}
```

Comment: This helped. Turns out it spent 4 minutes deallocating.